# How can I get information about children of some StorageReference?

Tags: java, firebase

I need to visit all children of my StorageReference in a loop. How can i do this? Neither the documentation nor stackoverflow mentions this. Help me please.

Comment: Please include what code you have tried and an example of your data.

Comment: I don't even know which code to try. If you can call the "children" method in DatabaseReference, then it is not in StorageReference.

Comment: Try `listAll()` methods [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud Storage’s List API as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files).

One way to use `listAll()`:

```
StorageReference listRef = storage.getReference().child("files/uid");

listRef.listAll()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for (StorageReference prefix : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                // All the prefixes under listRef.
                // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
            }

            for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                // All the items under listRef.
            }
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        }
    });
```